# FB credits App Not Responding

Tags: amazon-ec2, facebook-credits

Just came back to a simple FB credits application that used to work but now just returns "App Not Responding"

Seen a few earlier posts about this (eg http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7188998/integrating-facebook-credits-results-in-the-application-you-are-using-is-not-re and http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/8166977/credits-callback-script-not-called-error-1383046) but they seem to relate to URL/access errors.

Our server is on EC2 and the callback is accessible via HTTP and HTTPS from anywhere yet it is never hit... the Apache logs show the initial request to the application but not the callback... tried using elastic IP as well as a CNAME mapped to the AWS generated DNS name (no elb involved)

Have created a new test app on FB, installed latest FB sample code, changed the APP_ID and SECRET as required but this behaves exactly the same way

We also get 1151 errors form time to time (http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7429519/fb-credits-error-1151) but all the apps are in FB iframes so this is also confusing

Is there some validation on the associated company that FB do in here? - could it be that we have been 'blacklisted' as the app was dormant for several months? Could a missing privacy policy cause this?

Comment: in your app settings, have you correctly configured the `credits callback url`?

Comment: hard to say - I have put the URL of the callback in there - pasted from a browser where it works ok - that is correct as I understand it - but it does not work so maybe there is something I am missing?

Comment: are you sure that the facebook servers can reach your EC2 instance?  You can test it with the [facebook Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug), its an unrelated tool - but it utilizes facebook crawling techniques as it scans the url for `og` tags.

Comment: Yes - did try that earlier - should have said!

Comment: I'm having the same issue: http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/8291211/callback-not-being-pinged-for-credits

Comment: It started working again for me about midnight EST. Working for you?

Comment: No joy - just saw your comment and got all excited - but no change :(